# how to run other BackgroundWorker if first BackgroundWorker Complete in one method

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

How run other backgroundWorker if main backgroundworker complete in one method ?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CopyWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
   EnkripsiWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
   CompressWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

I want to try run in one click, but only first BackgroundWorker is running. So, How to run all BackgroundWorker. whether it can be done?

like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CopyWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    if (CopyWorker.RunWorkerCompleted == true)
    {
       EncryptWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    if (EnkripsiWorker.RunWorkerCompleted == true)
    {
          CompressWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
 }
```

I fixed it, and the code is correct
[EDIT]

```
CopyWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
CopyWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, a) => EnkripsiWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
EnkripsiWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, a) => Compress.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: It does not make sense to write code like this.  Just have CopyWorker *also* do the job of Encryptworker.  And EnkripsiWorker to the job of CompressWorker.  Albeit that it makes very little sense to run CompressWorker twice.  Take a look at the Task class, you'll have better odds getting this right.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start each successive `BackgroundWorker` in the previous `BackgroundWorker`'s `RunWorkerCompleted` event.

```
private void CopyWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)  // no error occurred
        EnkripsiWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void EnkripsiWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
        CompressWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Also, if `e.Error` is not `null`, then the `DoWork` event threw an exception, and you can handle it accordingly (log it, display a message, whatever).

---

If you wanted to be really verbose, and not do anything else in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event (including error checking!), you could shorten it:

```
CopyWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, a) => EnkripsiWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
EnkripsiWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, a) => CompressWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
CopyWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Although there'd be little sense in doing this, as you could just combine the three threads. At least in the first example, there's a chance to do other things in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event prior to starting the next thread.

Comment: I have done it. I want, if I can do it in one click if in button1_click without to write code in any 'RunWorkerCompleted' , can it be done?

Comment: you're right, i have modified your code. Thanks. I added if ('.IsBusy') every proses RunWorkerComplete, I'll fix it in my post.